# Search and retrieve data from Database using PHP and MY SQL(In android application)

Tags: php, android, mysql

Iam Developing a shopping application where the items are displayed in a scroll view.

On click of one of the items must take the required fields , search it in Database using PHP and MY SQL and display the exact product in the application.

**Problem:**

I am able to pass the values to database , if I search it in database and display it the value returns null.

Please find the Java class and php file.

**FullImage.java:**

```
public class FullImage extends AppCompatActivity
{
    ImageView fullimage;
    TextView name, des, price;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String model_grid, name_grid, price_grid, name_full = null, price_full = null, image_full;
    ArrayList < RowItem > val_grid_full = new ArrayList < > ();
    RowItem row1_grid = new RowItem();
    URL url = null;
    BufferedReader reader;
    String text;
    Context context_tab1;
    String rate = "Rs ";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

        // get intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();
        // Selected image id

        model_grid = in .getExtras().getString("model");
        name_grid = in .getExtras().getString("name");
        price_grid = in .getExtras().getString("price");

        fullimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_full);
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_name);
        des = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_des);
        price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_full);
        new DataFromServer().execute();
    }

    public class DataFromServer extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(FullImage.this, "", "Please wait...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String...params)
        {
            try
            {
                url = new URL("http://xxx");

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "xxx.com");

                Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("m", model_grid)
                    .appendQueryParameter("n", name_grid)
                    .appendQueryParameter("p", price_grid);

                String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(query);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();

                conn.connect();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }

                text = sb.toString();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.toString();
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    reader.close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.toString();
                }
            }
            return text;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String text)
        {
            //Close progress dialog
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            JSONArray ja;

            try
            {
                ja = new JSONArray(text);
                int len = ja.length();
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                {
                    JSONObject json_data = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                    name_full = json_data.getString("name");

                    image_full = json_data.getString("image");
                    price_full = json_data.getString("price");

                    RowItem rData1 = new RowItem();
                    rData1.setFull_grid_name(name_full);
                    rData1.setFull_grid_image(image_full);
                    rData1.setFull_grid_price(price_full);

                    val_grid_full.add(rData1);
                    name.setText(name_full);
                    price.setText(rate + (price_full));
                    String url = "xxx" + image_full;
                    Picasso.with(context_tab1).load(url).into(fullimage);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.toString();
            }

            // grid_shopping.setAdapter(new GridAdapter_tab1(Grid_tab1.this,val_grid_tab1));
        }
    }
}
```

**PHP.php:**

```
<?php
include('con.php');
$model = $_POST['m'];
$price = $_POST['p'];
$name = $_POST['n'];
$q=mysql_query("SELECT oc_product_description.name,oc_product.image,oc_product.price,oc_product.model FROM oc_product INNER JOIN oc_product_description ON oc_product.product_id = oc_product_description.product_id WHERE  model = '$model' and price = '$price' and name = '$name'");
while($e2=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
 $output[]=$e2;
}
print(json_encode($output));
?>
```

Please note that the above sql query is working fine.

It returns null only if I pass the POST values inside query.

Any Help would be Appreciated.

Comment: try this demo its help you more its best library for getting data from server :https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley

Comment: first of all stop using mysql_<function_name> functions. most of them are already removed in PHP 7.0 . I will recommend using MySQL PDO classes. for examples in PDO check this link http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for the time.

I have found the solution myself. Actually I used a String (Rs) for viewing the price along the string, which made the problem.

I pass the values to server along with the appended string. Once I replace the String with Blank space, it is working fine.

Changed from

```
in.putExtra("price",price_item);
```

to

```
 in.putExtra("price",price_item.replaceAll("Rs ",""));
```